# How to remove bing search on bing map?

Tags: bing-maps

I have reviewed almost all the option available with Bing Map, however, I could not found any option how to get rid of the search feature on bing map.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Bing Maps API's then you are using the Bing Maps V7 API which is the only map control that exposed this functionality. The Bing Maps V7 API was retired in June and will redirect to V8 starting Thursday. This feature was removed in Bing Maps V8.

Comment: This is what I am using for loading map 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0&s=1"></script>

but when i update to v=8.0 it throw 404 error

Comment: The V8 URL is https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol See the V7 to V8 migration guide here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34563.bing-maps-v7-to-v8-migration-guide.aspx